# Optimize unnesting of RProtoBuf protobuf messages

Tags: r, protocol-buffers, rcpp

Let's say we have this `.proto` file with a nested payload:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package optimize_nesting;

message TestPayload {
  int32 a = 1;
  int32 b = 2;
}

message NestedPayload {
    repeated TestPayload nested = 1;
}
```

One way of unnesting the message is to subset with `[[]]`, but that doesn't generalize/scale well to cases with a lot more than just two nested fields. Another could be:

```r
RProtoBuf::readProtoFiles("reprex.proto")

p <- optimize_nesting.NestedPayload$new(nested = list(
  optimize_nesting.TestPayload$new(a = 123,
                                   b = 456),
  optimize_nesting.TestPayload$new(a = 000,
                                   b = 999)
))

map_df(p[["nested"]], ~tibble(a = .[["a"]],
                              b = .[["b"]]))

## using [[]]
  tibble(a = c(p$nested[[1]][[1]], 
               p$nested[[1]][[2]]),
         b = c(p$nested[[2]][[1]], 
               p$nested[[2]][[2]]))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   123   456
2     0   999
```

Some Benchmarks:

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min        lq      mean   median
     purrr 1014.667 1125.5450  1689.671 1280.791
      base  487.676  514.3695  583.3068  532.079
```

Is this the fastest way of going from nested messages to workable tibble? Should this be done in `Rcpp` instead?

Please take into account that the `NestedPayload` could include more than one type of message, not just `TestPayload` as shown here, so it needs to generalize. A perfect solution would work without hardcoding the names of the fields as columns.

Comment: (1) Have you tried an `Rcpp` solution? (2) If so, (2a) What did you try? (2b) Did you benchmark `[[` vs. `dplyr` vs. `Rcpp`? (3) If not, have you at least benchmarked `[[` vs. `dplyr`? Your question is "Is this the fastest way of going from nested messages to workable tibble?" Adequate prior research for asking such a question (in my opinion) is making clearer which solutions you have tried so far, whether you have a specific additional idea that you had a problem implementing, and at least benchmarking the solutions you do know about.

Comment: @duckmayr I added the benchmark to the question. Using `[[]]` is faster in this example, but it won't work as soon as I have more than a couple rows. Using `purrr` is a bit more general. I'm not sure how to use `RCpp` in this case. Should I just send the message object to `RCpp`? A nicer way should be to stay within `C++` until I get the data-frame I need, but I'm unsure how to do that

Comment: Good; you've *partially* answered your own question. The `[[` method seems to be much faster than `dplyr`. The remaining aspect to your question is whether an `Rcpp` solution would be faster. Please edit your question to include your attempts at such a solution explanation of the problem you're having. If you don't have any attempts because you don't know where to start, start by reading the introduction, quickref, and FAQ vignettes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html). (1/2)

Comment: If you're expecting someone to code up an `Rcpp` solution for you wholecloth without your own attempt, please be aware Stack Overflow isn't just a free code writing service. If you have an Rcpp solution without problems, but need to know if it could be more efficient, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (2/2)

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear regarding using `[[]]`: it is indeed fast, but it's hardcoded and not scalable. I thank you for the codereview link, will be useful. I am not expecting someone to write my code, but rather to nudge me in the right direction. e.g. if someone wrote for loops here, I would suggest try purrr/lapply.

Comment: Looking at [RProtoBuf's Github](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rprotobuf), you can see the `[[` method calls ([link](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rprotobuf/blob/a4526a54cebdd4b131542f1604af5f638cf1735e/R/00classes.R#L388)) the C++ code [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rprotobuf/blob/868ad27b2f6028827f2f36fa531ef58287fa72db/src/extractors.cpp#L61). I would study that code as a start to your own custom C++ solution.